# translation matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, iteration

I have a translation matrix in javascript which I can't seem to get working. If I have a single matrix I can access the different levels OK using the method I have used but as soon as I try to multiply it with another matrix I get an error: Internal error setting variable. Thanks for your comments.

```
function funct(number, number1) {
    var matrixATranslate = new Array();
    var matrixBTranslate = new Array();
    var matrixCTranslate = new Array();

    var matrixATranslate = [
        [1, number, 0, number1],
        [number1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];

    var matrixBTranslate = [
        [number],
        [number1],
        [0],
        [1]
    ];

    var row = 3, col = 4, add = 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < add; k++) {
                sum += matrixATranslate[i, k] * matrixBTranslate[k, j];
            }
            matrixCTranslate[i, j] = sum;
        }
    }
    Vars.transformedPoint.x = matrixCTranslate[0][0];
    Vars.transformedPoint.y = matrixCTranslate[0][0];
    return Vars.transformedPoint;
}

Vars.transformedPoint = funct(10, 20);
```

Comment: oh! Yes, that;s not an error. I'm using this inside a machine vision application which refers to variables created outside the scripting window in this way. If created within the scripting window then it's just the standard way of referring to variables, var.

Comment: `matrixBTranslate` is a vector and not a matrix, so the call `matrixBTranslate[k, j];` makes no sense, because j must alway be zero

Comment: Ahh! sorry - i was playing with the code and changed some things.

Comment: ahh sorry - was playing with the code and changed some things. row=2, col=0, add=3. I've got the c# version which works fine, if that would help? Don't know how to upload it here now unless in answer my own question

Comment: what result should the function return?

Answer (score 0):

Got the working code here.

```
var matrixATranslate = new Array();
var matrixBTranslate = new Array();
var matrixCTranslate = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        matrixCTranslate[i,j] = [ ];
    }
}

var matrixATranslate = [
[5,6,7,8],
[10,20,30,40],
[100,200,300,400]
];

var matrixBTranslate = [5,6,7,8];

matrixCTranslate[0][0]=matrixATranslate[2][3] * matrixBTranslate[0,0];
var varA=matrixCTranslate[0,0];
console.log(varA)
```

Comment: sorry, this is not js, i mean it is syntactic right, but something like `matrixCTranslate[i,j]`, `matrixBTranslate[0,0];` or `varA=matrixCTranslate[0,0];` makes no sense, because the comma operator does not act like array indicator in other languages. - and what is the answer?